# Testing Latency Logic Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, client, latency

I have been trying to test for latency for my server & client but Im not sure whether my logic is correct - I am testing this with a nodejs server

Right now, the client first creates a random string & initializes the start time:

```
random = uuid.v4();
var startTime = new Date();
```

After this a 'ping' message with the random string & startTime is sent to the server.
The server receives the 'ping' and then sends a 'ping' message back to the client who sent it with the random string included.

Now the client should receive the 'ping' from the server and it checks whether the random string matches the one it created.

```
var endTime = new Date();

if (message.random == random) {
  var startTime = message.start1;
  ping = endTime.getTime() - startTime;
}
```

My issue is that Im not sure whether this is the best way to ping the server with the random string stored locally on the client.

It works find when a 'ping' msg is sent from the client every 1000ms but trying with 100ms or with 2+ clients renders this set up useless. This is because the var random on the client side will get overwritten when the next 'ping' msg is sent.

Any thoughts or advice? :]

Comment: easy: don't send the next one until the first one comes back.

Comment: hmm . . . haha thanks idk why I didnt consider waiting but that does make alot of sense

Comment: you can also use a function that generates the request and defines a callback function both inside that new wrapper function which could be sensibly called runRequest(). that way, it can be called many times, and each copy of "random" will be private to that callback.

Comment: That would work too but Im not sure how or even if it's possible to set that up with pubnub that Im using as my signaling backend. I do like that idea & might try to get that set up if time permits. Thanks again ! :]

Comment: well, pubnub is a whole different matter, it's not a traditional round-trip process like ajax, it's 2way and data can come and go at any time. in that case, you can store your random in a collection, call it randoms: randoms[random]=new Date(); then in your on() handler, you ask if (messages[message.random]){ console.log("lag", new Date() - messages[message.random]); } instead of matching a single case.

Comment: Hmm seems you have experience with pubnub. I'll definitely try your suggestion, both were very helpful!